# Pass data from Activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some problems to pass data from my activity to my fragment with the method onBackPressed()
My activity

```
    public class SingleArticle extends Activity {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: 

            onBackPressed();

            break;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }



    }
```

On my fragment I have this

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
   public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        Log.e("RETURN", "test = " );

    }
}
```

The problem is that I can not see the log ...
Do you have any idee how to resolve this ? Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html read this :)

Comment: You means you want to pass the data from SingleArticle to Home on  onBackPressed(). Simple send and receive the intent, see here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to pass data to fragment

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Context,fragment_class_name.class);
    intent.putExtra(key, Value);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is for data share between Activities. He want it between Activity and Fragment.

Comment: We can access it in fragment by using of below code

       **Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();**
and then retrieve data from intent using 

      **String var= intent.getStringExtra(Ckey);**

Comment: Other fragment should be in other activity right? This is the case while changing the fragments in a single activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Pass the data from Activity to Fragment
    Fragment newFragment=new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("item_id",1);
    bundle.putString("item_data","description goes here");
    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,newFragment, "newFragmentTag");
    ft.commit();

    //retrieve the data inside fragment
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    int id = bundle.getInt("item_id", 0);
    String data = bundle.getString("item_data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to pass data from an Activity to a Fragment:

Create a static newInstance() method in the Fragment class:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String valueToPass) {
    MyFragment instance = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key", valueToPass);
    instance.setArguments(args)
    return instance;
}
```

Pass the data from the Activity/Fragment to MyFragment like so:

```
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance("Hello World");
```

Then you can do this to retrieve the data (any time after Fragment.onCreate())

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       if (getArguments() != null) {
           String passedValue = getArguments().getString("key");
           // passedValue == "Hello World"
       }   
   }
```